# Converting integers to hex string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, hex

How do I convert integer byte values of red, green and blue to a hex string, which can then be assigned to a context for rendering onto a HTML5 canvas?

For example, convert cyan,

```
var r = 0;
var g = 255;
var b = 255;
```

To a hex string for assigning to a context fill colour.

```
this.context.fillStyle = '#00FFFF';
```

Or is there a better way to do this altogether?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just use the RGB values, like:

```
this.context.fillStyle = "rgb(0,255,255)";
```

Comment: The best answers are always the simplest!

Comment: But thanks everyone else who replied, they were interesting answers and valuable to my knowledge & understanding. +1 each.

Comment: Is this cross-browser compatible?

Comment: @ElRonnoco According to [one person's post](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum83/614.htm) it works in NN7+, IE5+, Mozilla 1.0+. So yes, very cross-browser compatible. _(The same [cannot be said](http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/) for `rgba(...)`.)_

Comment: Oi.  This is not answering the question asked.  The answer below, Number(integer).toString(16) is correct and should be accepted.

Comment: The original question asked should have been _"I have values of red, green and blue, how do I assign this to a fill colour for a HTML5 canvas ?"_  I really provided an answer for the 2nd part: _"Or a better way to do this altogether!"_

Comment: Not answering the original question!

Comment: @DavidFischer answering the 2nd part of the question I think

Answer (score 38):

To convert a number to hex, you can use the built-in toString(16) function.
Simple code:

```
function convert(integer) {
    var str = Number(integer).toString(16);
    return str.length == 1 ? "0" + str : str;
};

function to_rgb(r, g, b) { return "#" + convert(r) + convert(g) + convert(b); }

var color = to_rgb(r, g, b);
```

Answer (score 14):

I think, the simplest way is:

```
var g = 255;
g.toString(16); //gives "ff"
```

Use the feature that gives language.

Comment: This answer is missing the 0-padding necessary for hexadecimal color values.

Comment: '0x' + g.toString(16), add a prefix is pretty simple

Comment: You can use `padStart` for this: `g.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')`

Answer (score 4):

Convert one integer to a hex byte like:

```js
const g = 255;

gPadded = Number(g).toString(16).padStart(2, "0");
```

This gets nicer with an array:

```js
const r = 0;
const g = 255;
const b = 255;
const color = [r, g, b];

this.context.fillStyle = "#" + color.map(i=>i.toString(16).padStart(2, "0")).join("");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function pad(number, length) {
    var str = '' + number;
    while (str.length < length) str = '0' + str;
    return str;
}

function toRGBHex(r,g,b) { 
    return pad(r.toString(16),2) + pad(g.toString(16),2) + pad(b.toString(16),2); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To convert your individual RGB values into a hex color, you can use this function, although it makes more sense just to use `"rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+")"` instead.

```
function rgbToHex(r,g,b) {
    return "#"+("00000"+(r<<16|g<<8|b).toString(16)).slice(-6);
}
```

Comment: ~ fyi I have incorporated your edit to my answer, despite it having been rejected. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17945972/converting-rgba-values-into-one-integer-in-javascript/17946089#17946089 (no good way to send message here)

Comment: @MightyPork oh, alright, thanks for telling me.  Yeah, there should be a way to inbox people on here.  Oh well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **`.toString(16)`**

```js
let decimalNumber = 255;
decimalNumber.toString(16)
// Expected output is "FF"
```

or if you want to convert binary **radix**

```js
let decimalNumber = 24;
decimalNumber.toString(2)
// Expected output is "1010"
```

[source MDN .toString(16)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString#:%7E:text=toString(2))

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own method for this conversion -

```
// function to generate the hex code
function getHex(dec)
{
    var hexArray = new Array( "0", "1", "2", "3", 
                              "4", "5", "6", "7",
                              "8", "9", "A", "B", 
                              "C", "D", "E", "F" );

    var code1 = Math.floor(dec / 16);
    var code2 = dec - code1 * 16;

    var decToHex = hexArray[code2];

    return (decToHex);
}
```

original source - http://programming.top54u.com/post/Javascript-Convert-Decimal-to-Hex.aspx

Comment: This will only convert one nibble.

Comment: @El Ronnoco - Please check the link. We run a loop for calling this function when decimal number is greater than 15.

Comment: @Tomas - that depends on how you want to use it. I think I have given a link of already existing code which is open for your customization. Dont you think downvote is a bit harsh here?

Comment: The link seems to be broken.

Comment: link seems broken, I don't know why this should be downvoted?! It's a valid function.